# jslint clickHandler was used before it was defined/is already defined

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have recently started using JSLint and like many I faced the "used before defined" and "is already defined". I went through some of the solutions here and I did manage to fix some of my problems, but now I am stuck. My code is something like this:

```
var foo;   
foo = addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);  
... 
function clickHandler() {...};
```

This way the code works, but I get the "used before defined" warning. If I add clickHandler to the "var", then by the time I call it, it will be undefined, forcing me to reorder my code and putting the definition of the handler in the middle of the code (less readability in my opinion). Is there a way I can call use the clickHandler and yet have its definition after it was used?

Comment: OK, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had written the question part. Fixed it.

Comment: I'm wondering why jslint is balking at this. `function foo()` is interpreted at *load* time (i.e. first) while `var foo=function()` is interpreted at *run* time (i.e. later). Your code should run unless you switch to the `var foo=function()` style declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you restructure your code to

```
function clickHandler() {...};
var foo;   
foo = addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);  
...
```

> Is there a way I can call use the clickHandler and yet have its definition after it was used?

Sure, just keep the code like it is. It will **work**. JSLint just points out possible problems or style violations. Not everything that it complains about is actually a problem.

If you want a more flexible linter, use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: That would work, but would make me define all my functions in the beginning of the document rather than in the end. As a matter of style, I really prefer the definition of functions in the end as I find it more readable (first the logic of the main program, and then the details).

Comment: Then you're out of luck using JSLint.  ;^)  You've got to do what Felix has here to pass muster.

Comment: @Tiagojdferreira: As ruffin says, then don't use JSLint. Use JSHint which is more configurable.